# File browse inside datatables row

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

I'm using [datatables](https://datatables.net/) to show some fields and two file upload button like below.

[image: file upload inside datatable]

I would like to click on browse and then, after file secetion, call a web service to store file on the server and show the name beside the button, in the input field.
The problem is that the datatable is created from javascript:

```
function createDatatableTable(){
    if ( ! $.fn.DataTable.isDataTable( '#datatableTable' ) ) {
        datatableTable = $('#datatableTable').DataTable({
            responsive: true,
            columnDefs: [
                         {
                             targets: [3,4,5],
                             //set priority to column, so when resize the browser window this botton stay on the screen because have max priority
                             responsivePriority: 1,
                             orderable: false,
                             searchable: false,
                         }
                         ],
                         //fix problem with responsive table
                         "autoWidth": false,
            "ajax":{ 
                "url":  "datatable/" + $("#selectedCar").val(),
                "dataSrc": function ( json ) {
                    if (typeof json.success == 'undefined')
                        window.location.href = "/DART/500";
                    else if (json.success){
                        return json.result.data;
                    }else{
                        notifyMessage(json.result, 'error');   
                        return "";
                    }                           
                },  
                "error": function (xhr, error, thrown) {
                    window.location.href = "/DART/500";
                }
            },
            "columns": [
                        { "data": "date",
                            "render": function (data) {
                                return (moment(data).format("DD/MM/YYYY"));                  
                            }
                        },
                        { "data": "idShift" },
                        { data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return data.beginKm - initialKm;
                        }
                        },
                        { data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="btn btn-primary file-upload"> Browse&hellip; <input id="dat" type="file" name="file"/></span></span> <input id="datFileName" target="'+row.idAcquisition+'"  type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></div>'  
                        }
                        },
                        { data:null, render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="otherFiles">Other</button>'

                        }
                        },
                        { data: "isShown", render: function ( data, type, row ) {
                         if (data) {
                             return '<input data="'+row.idAcquisition+'" type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox" checked>';
                         }
                         else {
                             return '<input data="'+row.idAcquisition+'" type="checkbox" name="my-checkbox">';
                         }
                        }   
                        },
                        ],
                        "fnDrawCallback": function() {
                         //Initialize checkbox for enable/disable user
                         $("[name='my-checkbox']").bootstrapSwitch({size: "small", onColor:"success", offColor:"danger"});
                        },
        });
    }
    else {
        datatableTable.ajax.url("datatable/" + $("#selectedCar").val()).load();
    }
```

In this way I have given one unique id to the text area where I have to write but now how can I know the row clicked?
I have used:

```
//File dat upload
$('#datatableTable').on('change', 'input[name="file"]', function(event) {
        var input = $(this),
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        var fieldFileName="datFileName"+ document.getElementById("datFileName").getAttribute("target");
        document.getElementById(fieldFileName).value = label;
        //uploadFunction('dat');
});
```

but it returns always the same id so use only the first file browse. I check and the id are all right.
I shouuld use an approach like `var test= $(this).parent().parent().parent();` and the get the id of child?
I have used this approach for my switch button and it works:

```
$('#datatableTable').on('switchChange.bootstrapSwitch', 'input[name="my-checkbox"]', function(event, state) {
        //CSRF attribute for spring security
        var token = $("meta[name='_csrf']").attr("content");
        var header = $("meta[name='_csrf_header']").attr("content");
        $.ajax({
            type : "POST",
            url : "status/" + $(this).attr('data') + "/" + state,
```

**RESOLVED**:
I fix the problem using in datatables

```
return '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="btn btn-primary file-upload"> Browse&hellip; <input id="dat" type="file" name="file" target="'+row.idAcquisition+'"/></span></span> <input id="'+row.idAcquisition+'" type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></div>'
```

and using

```
$('#datatableTable').on('change', 'input[name="file"]', function(event) {
        var input = $(this),
        label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
        var test= $(this).attr('target');
        document.getElementById(test).value = label;
 //      uploadFunction('dat');
});
```

Comment: If you have such problems with complex code I suggest you isolate the problem before posting first. It seems this problem is not really related to dataTables but multiple same IDs. You could have tested this in a static HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Per definition an element ID must be unique throughout the whole document. Therefore

```
document.getElementById("datFileName")
```

and

```
$("#datFileName") // jQuery equivalent
```

will only return the first element with the given id. It seems though that in your table every row has the same element IDs inside.

---

Here's how you can make the IDs unique:

The [`columns.render`](https://datatables.net/reference/option/columns.render#function) function is given 4 arguments (although you're using only 3 of them). The fourth is `meta`and it has a field called `row` which is an index for the currently processed row. Use this to generate your ID:

```
...
{ data:null, render: function ( data, type, row, meta ) {
    var idDat = "dat" + meta.row;
    var idDatFN = "datFileName" + meta.row;
    return '<div class="input-group"><span class="input-group-btn"><span class="btn btn-primary file-upload"> Browse&hellip; <input id="'+id+'" type="file" name="file"/></span></span> <input id="'+idDatFN+'" target="'+row.idAcquisition+'"  type="text" class="form-control" readonly="readonly"></div>'  
}
...
```

---

An alternative to this approach that is possibly cleaner is not giving the fields IDs at all but referencing them as siblings and their `:nth-of-type(n)` selectors. Consider reading the jQuery docs for that.

Example:

```
$('#datatableTable').on('change', 'input[name="file"]', function(event) {
    var input = $(this),
    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
    // find the input's first ancestor with class input-group and inside it
    // look for an input of type=text. then set its value
    input.parent(".input-group").find("input[type=text]").val(label);
});
```

---

Not related the the actual problem, but you're also using the data attribute wrong. Instead of

```
<element data="bar" />
```

you should use

```
<element data-foo="bar" />
```

This way you can have multiple data attributes on each element and you can access them easily through jQuery like this:

```
$("element").data("foo") // getter
$("element").data("foo", "no bar") // setter
```

Comment: yes, but my problem is in the $('#datatableTable').on('change', 'input[name="file"]', I handle event on file class but I need to change the value of class="form-control"

Comment: Could you elaborate on this? I fear I don't understand the problem.

Comment: Added a correct version of your onChange listener. If you want it cleaner, access the fields by css class names instead of input type.